# Console command for creating dummy data to DB in the mature Yii1 project

Tags: php, web, activerecord, yii, fixtures

I have a task to prepare a web application(service) for better local development. In the dev environment, It uses a database that is partly dumped from the production. This approach is not the best solution for us now. So we have to dump only the schema of DB and then fill the local database with dummy data.

My goal: A console command which creates fixtures. It can be something like [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-console-controllers-fixturecontroller) but it is Yii2 :(.

In this situation I face a couple of questions:

1. I learned out that Yii1 has a special tool for creating fixtures - [Defining Fixtures](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture)  but it is described in a topic about tests. How difficult is it to use this tool for my purpose? Do I have to write a console command by myself or does an easier way exists?
2. Can someone advise the special libraries for fixtures, that I can "plugin and use" for Yii and its active records? I'd like to use [DoctrineFixturesBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/current/index.html), but it is for only ORM, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For using the fixtures you can do the following:

Create a new [command](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console) called:

`protected\commands\FixtureCommand.php`

With the following contents:

```
<?php

Yii::import('system.test.CDbFixtureManager');

class FixtureCommand extends CConsoleCommand {

  public function actionIndex() {
    
    /* @var $fixtureManager CDbFixtureManager */
    $fixtureManager=new CDbFixtureManager();
    $fixtureManager->basePath=Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.my_fixtures');
    $fixtureManager->init();

    // Just print some info about the tables
    foreach ($fixtureManager->getFixtures() as $name => $path) {
      echo "Loaded {$name} table from {$path}\n";
    }
    
  }

}
```

Now create a directory `protected/my_fixtures`.

And create some fixtures:

`protected\my_fixtures\project.php`

```
<?php

return array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Red project',
        'company' => 'Red Ltd',
        'open' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Blue project',
        'company' => 'Blue Ltd',
        'open' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Green project',
        'company' => 'Green Ltd',
        'open' => 0,
    ),
);
```

`protected\my_fixtures\task.php`

```
<?php

return array(
    array(
        'project_id' => '1',
        'description' => 'Get the milk',
        'completed' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'project_id' => '1',
        'description' => 'Get the eggs',
        'completed' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'project_id' => '1',
        'description' => 'Walk the dog',
        'completed' => 0,
    ),
);
```

Finally, go to the terminal and run the command:

```
C:\Projects\fixtureapp\protected>c:\xampp\php56\php.exe yiic.php fixture
Loaded project table from C:\Projects\fixtureapp\protected\my_fixtures\project.php
Loaded task table from C:\Projects\fixtureapp\protected\my_fixtures\task.php
```

You can find the full example project here on Github:

https://github.com/atrandafir/yii-1-fixtures

Other tips:

- I hope that you do use [database migrations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration) in order to keep your schema structure the same between develop and production instances.
- I really recommend [reading the API](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1), the documentation of Yii classes, and have "the courage" to use them and customize them, feel free to open the clases files and look at what is it exactly they do
- If the current [fixtures manager class](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.fixture) doesn't do what you want, you could also extend and override its methods, or even write a new one based on [the origial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbFixtureManager)